# In Polish/Prefix notation of binary operations, are all expression unambiguous w.r.t. which operator is applied first?

Tags: binary-operations, associativity

Take binary operator `~` and a chain like `a ~ b ~ c`. It is ambiguous as it can mean  either of:

1. `(a ~ b) ~ c`
2. `a ~ (b ~ c)`

That is to say, expressed in infix notation, the expression is ambiguous when the parentheses are omitted.

Written in Polish/prefix notation however, there is no ambiguity even if we omit the parentheses:

1. `(a ~ b) ~ c` becomes `~(~(a b) c)` which without parentheses is `~~abc`
2. `a ~ (b ~ c)` becomes `~(a ~(b c))` which without parentheses is `~a~bc`

Are there scenarios where Polish/prefix notation can be ambiguous?

I went over all permutations of `~~abc` trying to find an ambiguous Polish/prefix notation expression, but none were ambiguous:

```
ab~c~  # invalid, string must start with `~`
abc~~  # invalid, string must start with `~`
~a~bc  # This is #2 above.
a~b~c  # invalid, string must start with `~`
ab~~c  # invalid, string must start with `~`
~~abc  # This is #1 above.
~abc~  # invalid, string cannot end with `~`
a~bc~  # invalid, string must start with `~`
~ab~c  # invalid, the second `~` only has one operand
a~~bc  # invalid, string must start with `~`
```

I have tested only the bare minimum (a chain of two applications of the binary operation); I could try three, four, etc, but probably someone here knows the answer.

Comment: This is correct.    Polish notation can even combine any number of binary and unary operations.

Comment: Your question does't make sense. I think you mean "prefix" or "Polish" in most places where you write "infix". The prefix/Polish notation is unambiguous in the sense that any string that can be parsed can only be parsed in one way. As your list of examples shows there are many strings that can't be parsed at all.

Comment: @RobArthan, thanks. Fixed the typos.